# How to stop a spec execution in protractor on first expect failure

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I want to stop spec execution on first expect failure and continue with the rest specs execution

Answer (score 0):

To stop test execution of first expect failure I'm using `jasmine-fail-fast` please have a look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-fail-fast#protractor).

To use it, you just need to add:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  ...
  var failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
  ...
}
```

to your `protractor.conf.js` file.

I'm not sure about

> ..and continue with the rest specs execution

this part of your question. Protractor is doing this by default without any external libraries or tricks.

Comment: it not working. spec execution continue after first expect failure